# Select rows which come before a certain value

Tags: sql, oracle

For the example table, how do I select all saleIDs which have the status as accepted but are followed by a denied. For example ABC123 and A12B12 will be returned as after their accepted status following sales are denied.

A1B2C3 will not be returned as it is not followed by a denied status.

```
saleID | Fruit | Status   | Date
______________________________________
ABC123 | Apple | Accepted | 18/06/2020
--------------------------------------
123ABC | Apple | Denied   | 19/06/2020
--------------------------------------
1A2B3C | Banana| Denied   | 20/06/2020
--------------------------------------
A1B2C3 | Banana| Accepted | 21/06/2020
--------------------------------------
A12B12 | Pear  | Accepted | 22/06/2020
--------------------------------------
ABC123 | Pear  | Declined | 23/06/2020
```

Thanks.

Comment: What if there are multiple accepts/denies for a sales id?

Comment: umm yes that could be a possibility

Comment: This could be a job for [`match_recognize()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1), but will take a bit of thought to set up a demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should select all accepted rows that have
a direct follower that is denied.

It is not very efficienct but can be fast enough
depending on the count of rows with status=accepted

```
-- follow means a greater date value
SELECT * FROM 
  (
  SELECT 
    t1.*, 
    -- min date of all denied follower
    (SELECT MIN(t2.date) FROM tbl t2 
      WHERE t2.fruit = t1.fruit -- same fruit
      AND t2.date > t1.date -- greater date
      AND t2.status = 'Denied') AS follower_denied,
    -- min date of all accepted follower
    (SELECT MIN(t2.date) FROM tbl t2 
      WHERE t2.fruit = t1.fruit -- same fruit
      AND t2.date > t1.date -- greater date
      AND t2.status = 'Accepted') AS follower_accepted
  FROM tbl t1 
  WHERE status = 'Accepted'
  ) v
WHERE 
  v.follower_denied IS NOT NULL
  AND v.follower_denied < NVL(v.follower_accepted, v.follower_denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select saleid
from t
group by saleid
having max(case when status = 'Accepted' then date end) < min(case when status = 'Declined' then ate end);
```

This works if there is only one accepted/denied.  If there are multiple values, then this compares the latest accepted to the earliest denied -- that seems like a reasonable interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Analytical function LEAD() -

```
SELECT sale_id
FROM (
    SELECT sale_id, fruit, status, sale_date, LEAD(status) OVER(PARTITION BY fruit ORDER BY sale_date) next_fruit_status
    FROM sales)
WHERE status = 'Accepted'
  AND next_fruit_status IS NOT NULL
  AND status <> next_fruit_status
ORDER BY 1;
```